# Implementing PHP Activerecord in self made MVC Framework

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm trying to implement a PHPActiveRecord for my own tiny PHP MVC Framework. But it only work for several table, and won't work for other table. 
OK, my MVC structure like this:

```
index.php
 - assets
 - config/
 - core/
 -   Bootstrap.php
 -   Controller.php
 -   Model.php 
 -   View.php
 -   etc
 - libs/
 -  php-activerecord/
 -    ActiveRecord.php
 -    others
 - app/
 -  activerecords/
 -  controllers/
 -  models/
 -  views/
```

How i implement Activerecord is like this:

Model.php

```
class Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once 'libs/php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

        ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg)
        {     
            $cfg->set_model_directory('app/activerecords');
            $cfg->set_connections(array(
                 'development' => 'mysql://root:@localhost/db_name'));
        });
    }
}
```

For Example, I have 2 table, cities and laboratories. 
The problem is when retrieving data from cities, it works well, but when retrieving data from laboratories it got an error : "call to undefined method Laboratory::find"

Here is the codes:
Table Cities

Location : activerecords/City.php

```
class City extends ActiveRecord\Model
{

}
```

Table Laboratories

Location : activerecords/Laboratory.php

```
    class Laboratory extends ActiveRecord\Model
    {

    }
```

Index Controller

Location : controllers/indexController.php

```
class Index extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        Session::init();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->view->cityLists = $this->model->getCityLists();
            $this->view->laboratoryLists = $this->model->getLaboratoryLists();
        $this->view->render('home/index');  
    }
}
```

Model

Location : models/indexModel.php

```
class indexModel extends Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
    }

    function getLaboratoryLists()
    {
        return Laboratory::find('all');
    }

    function getCityLists()
    {
            return City::find('all');
    }
}
```

Views

Location : views/home/index.php

```
foreach($this->cityLists as $key){
    echo $key->id.' - '.$key->name;
}

foreach($this->laboratoryLists as $key){
    echo $key->id.' - '.$key->name;
}
```

In the browser, the list of Cities is can be loaded, but it can load the data from table laboratories.
The browser says: "call to undefined method Laboratory::find"

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my codes? is this because of the conventions of PHPActiveRecord or other?

Thanks Before... and sory for my poor english..

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you, but "model" in MVC is **not** a class or object. Model is a layer, that is made up from multitude of classes.

Comment: While that may be true, the `phpactiverecord` library does have a class called `model` and this is what the question seems to be about. The 'model' multitude of classes all extend this class. Nice topic for somewhere maybe, but not really relevant to the question

Comment: ontopic: how are your namespaces defined? Could it be that something funny is going on there?